# A stronger concept than total boundness

Tags: general-topology, uniform-convergence, uniform-spaces

A space, every proper principal filter of which is refined by a Cauchy filter, is called *totally bounded*.

Is there a term (and theory) about a stronger concept: a space every proper filter of which is refined by a Cauchy filter?

Comment: Hm, it means I err saying that for a space to by totally bounded it's enough for every proper principal filter to be refined by a Cauchy filter. (I can't find a reference where have I got this statement about principal filters from. Maybe, I've just confused principal and proper filter.)

Answer (score 1):

I found, it is called *precompact*:
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/precompact+space

Comment: It seems from http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/precompact+space that "totally bounded" and "precompact" are the same. But I need a proof of this